# How to fill fields in a Struct type? error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: c, malloc

Having trouble using malloc to create each row vector to store data in. Also, I can't seem to assign the fields of struct using functions I've coded.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#include "redo_hw4_functs.h"

typedef struct _Stores{
    char name[10];
    char addr[50];
    char city[30];
    char state[3];
} Store;

//function that creates a new matrix of size r x c




int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
Store* pStores;
FILE* pFile;
    char* stateGiven;
    char buffer[180];
    char* storeGiven;
    char lineChar;
    int lineNumb = 0;
    int r;
    char* tempName, tempAddr, tempCity, tempState;
    
    if(argc < 4){
            printf("Too few arguments! \n");
        }
        else if(argc > 4){
            printf("Too many arguments! \n");
        }

    pFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    
     for (lineChar = getc(pFile); lineChar != EOF; lineChar = getc(pFile))
     {
     if (lineChar == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
         lineNumb = lineNumb + 1;
         
     }
    fclose(pFile);
    
    pFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    
    
    
    
         
     while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pFile) != NULL)
     {
         for (r = 0; r < lineNumb; r++)
         {
             pStores = realloc(pStores, lineNumb * sizeof(Store*));
             
             Store pStores[r] = malloc(sizeof(Store));
             
             
         
         
         getName(pStores[r].name, buffer);

        getAddress(pStores[r].addr, buffer);

         getCity(pStores[r].city, buffer);

         getState(pStores[r].state, buffer);
         
         
         
         
             printf(" Store name: %s \n", pStores[r].name);
         printf(" Address: %s \n", pStores[r].addr);
         printf(" City: %s \n", pStores[r].city);
         printf(" State: %s \n", pStores[r].state);
                     
        
         }
         
         
         
     }
    



}
```

^^^ In the above block of code I made some improvements and also included realloc(). I initialized the lineNumb variable. I believe the problem regarding my initialization of each row that `Store* pStores` is trying to reference/point to.

Here are the helper functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


#include "redo_hw4_functs.h"



//accepts a line of string formatted as expected and stores the store name in char file
void getName(char strName[], char strLine[])
{
    char* token;
    char delim[] = " ,\t\n";
    
    token = strtok(strLine, delim);
    
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(token, "sears") == 0 || strcmp(token, "kmart"))
        {
            strcpy(strName, token);
            break;
        }
        
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    
    
    
    
}

//accepts a line of string formatted as expected and stores the store address in char file
void getAddress(char strAddress[], char strLine[])
{
    
    char* token;
    char delim[] = ",\t\n";
    
    token = strtok(strLine, delim);
    
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(isdigit(token[0]) && isalpha(token[sizeof(token)-1]))
        {
            strcpy(strAddress, token);
            break;
        }
        
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    
}

//accepts a line of string formatted as expected and stores the store city in char file
void getCity(char strCity[], char strLine[])
{
    int i;
    char* token;
    char delim[] = ",\t\n";
    
    token = strtok(strLine, delim);
    
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        
        strcpy(strCity, token + strlen(token)-3);
        
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
}

//accepts a line of string formatted as expected and stores the store state in char file ¡OJO! This is the hardest one because you cant rely on delimeters alone to find state 
void getState(char strState[], char strLine[])
{
    int i;
    char* token;
    char delim[] = "\n";
    
    token = strtok(strLine, delim);
    
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        
        strcpy(strState, token + strlen(token)-3);
        
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    
        
       
    
    
}
```

Here is some sample input:

Kmart, 217 Forks Of River Pkwy, Sevierville TN
Kmart, 4110 E Sprague Ave, Spokane WA
Kmart, 1450 Summit Avenue, Oconomowoc WI
Sears, 2050 Southgate Rd, Colorado Spgs CO
Sears, 1650 Briargate Blvd, Colorado Spgs CO
Sears, 3201 Dillon Dr, Pueblo CO

Comment: In the `while` loop that calls `getName` etc., `r` is at its limiting value `lineNumb` already. It should go inside the `for` loop that iterates the `r` value.

Comment: In `main()` is `lineNumb` uninitialized?

Comment: Also note that `strtok` modifies the source string by overwriting an occurrence of the delimiter characters with '\0'. so after `getName` has overwritten parts of the source buffer, `getAddress` will only see the first part of the same buffer.

Comment: `pStores` is declared as a pointer to a `Stores` object or an array of them, but your code is treating it as if it were a pointer to an array of pointers.  Which do you want it to be?

Comment: The whole file was read in while counting the lines, incrementing `lineNumb` (which you need to initialize to 0). So the later `fgets` calls on the same file won't read anything. If the file is seekable, you could call `rewind` on the file pointer to reset it back to the beginning of the file, but a better option would be to only read the file in once and use `realloc` to dynamically resize the `pStores` memory as required.

Comment: Do not create identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an upper case letter, like `_Stores`. Those are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @IanAbbott I closed and reopened file so that ``` fgets ``` can read the file in. I also used realloc for ```Store* store ``` but not sure how to initialize each row pointer will refer too. I haven't even reached a point to see what is in the helper functions ```getName() getAddress ``` but I have gotten city and state to print successfully from other problem

Comment: @NateEldredge I want ```Store** pStores``` but I have been directed to do otherwise. Could you elaborate more on the difference between the too please?

Comment: I think you meant `pStores[r] = malloc(sizeof(Store));`